# angularfire2 installation and setup - need help understanding collection to a list example

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am new to Angular and angularfire2 and could use some help with the *Installation and Setup* examples provided at [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md).

I have followed all instructions to the point, but [#8. Bind a Firestore collection to a list](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md#8-bind-a-firestore-collection-to-a-list) is not working for me as described, no list is returned from `app.component.html`. When I add the `*ngFor` directive together with the `async` pipe to the template as shown in docs and run the app. It is just all blank, only the `{{title}}` is outputted. I get no errors in the console.

But if I `console.log(this.items);` It returns an `Observable` And as I understand it is expected since you need to `subscribe` to or use the `async` pipe on an `Observable`.

```
Observable
operator: MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object
```

Why is this simple example from the docs not working for me? Why am I not seeing the two documents I have stored in a collection in Firestore?

app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Animal list';
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}
```

app/app.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

src/environments/environments.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '...',
    authDomain: '...',
    databaseURL: '...',
    projectId: '...',
    storageBucket: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...'
  }
};
```

Comment: It sounds like the Observable contains an empty list

Comment: Oh, my god. Embarrassing, my face is all red. My collection is named "animals" and not "items". Too much copy/paste. Can you post that comment as an answer so I can close this question? Thanks for the help.